# Screen - Do command on start

Tags: command-line

I cannot find this anywhere on Google/SE, excuse me if it was just my wording.

I want to make screen do a command upon start. With pseudo code, doing

```
 screen -S SomeScreen -c SomeScript.sh
```

would make it execute SomeScript.sh automatically, without going into screen and typing this. Thanks!

(there is no tag for the screen command)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about "make screen do a command upon start"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the syntax in `man screen`:

```
screen [ -options ] [ cmd [ args ] ]
```

`cmd` is a command to run in the session. So, typing `screen SomeScript.sh` would make it execute SomeScript.sh automatically, without going into screen and typing this.

If you're looking for a way to have screen execute some command(s) every time you start a new session, I do it by putting them in ~/.screen-start and putting something like this at the end of .bashrc:

```
if [ -n "$STY" ]; then
  source ~/.screen-start
fi
```

Since screen sets $STY to the screen session identifier, you can test for whether it's set to know if screen is running. And since screen starts a login shell when invoked without a specific command, it will execute .bashrc.

There is probably a better way; I stopped looking since this worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-X` switch of `screen` (uppercase X, lowercase x means something else ;) ) to send a command to an existing screen session. So you can do something along the lines of

```
screen -md
screen -p 0 -X stuff $'echo "Test"\n'
screen -r
```

But I assume this doesn't fit your task of making things *easier* ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to carry out some execution at startup of the OS...

go to `startup applications` and add this command to the list there by selecting `add`.

You can get to startup applications by pressing the windows key and typing it in.

Comment: I meant to make it execute on screen start, but thanks for trying to help.